# Maven resource configures , include then exclude again?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Maven config form [spring-boot-starter-parent pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2129cf0d7fd64bf98086cee5204e8a551c496d3e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml#L27)

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/application*.yml</include>
            <include>**/application*.yaml</include>
            <include>**/application*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/application*.yml</exclude>
            <exclude>**/application*.yaml</exclude>
            <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Why those files need configured twice ? What is the purpose of the second one ?